# Getting a user input and storing it into an array, then comparing another user input to the array to check for duplicate answers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm fairly new at Java programming. What I'm basically doing is asking a user for a choice then will display an output. However, if the user already selected the same output, the system should be able to give a message then return to the loop again. Thanks! This is what I have so far:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String[] array1 = {"A","B","C","D"};

    for(int a=0; a<array1.length; a++)
    {
        System.out.print("\n Pick an exception: ");
        System.out.print("\n A. Arithmetic Exception");
        System.out.print("\n B. Array Out Of Bounds Exception");
        System.out.print("\n C. Array Store Exception");
        System.out.print("\n D. Number Format Exception");
        System.out.print("\n\nPick: ");
        pick = br.readLine();

        if(array1[a].equalsIgnoreCase ("a"))
        {
            //output1;
        }

        else if(array1[a].equalsIgnoreCase ("b"))
        {
            //output2;
        }
        else if(array1[a].equalsIgnoreCase ("c"))
        {
            ////output3;
        }
        else if(array1[a].equalsIgnoreCase ("d"))
        {
            //output4;
        }


        // PS If anyone can also let me know how I can display the user input depending to the sequence it was selected what would be great!

        System.out.print("\n\n Status: " +array1[a] + "\n\n ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? You don't actually say.

Comment: `pick = br.readLine();   pick = array1[a]` - you're ignoring the user input. That doesn't seem right...

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get an input either A, B, C or D and storing the input into the array. I'm having problems checking the array for any repeat inputs. 'Coz the system should not have duplicate inputs otherwise it will give an error message and return back to asking another user input.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's take a look at your original code.

```
    String[] array1 = {"A","B","C","D"};
    String pick = "";

    for(int a=0; a<array1.length; a++)
    {
        System.out.print("\n Pick an exception: ");
        System.out.print("\n A. Arithmetic Exception");
        System.out.print("\n B. Array Out Of Bounds Exception");
        System.out.print("\n C. Array Store Exception");
        System.out.print("\n D. Number Format Exception");
        System.out.print("\n\nPick: ");
        pick = br.readLine();
        pick = array1[a]

        if(array1[a].equalsIgnoreCase ("a"))
        {
            //output1;
        }

        else if(array1[a].equalsIgnoreCase ("b"))
        {
            //output2;
        }
        else if(array1[a].equalsIgnoreCase ("c"))
        {
            ////output3;
        }
        else if(array1[a].equalsIgnoreCase ("d"))
        {
            //output4;
        }


        // PS If anyone can also let me know how I can display the user input depending to the sequence it was selected what would be great!

        System.out.print("\n\n Status: " +array1[a] + "\n\n ");
    }
}
```

First, unless you have some other reason, there isn't a particular use to say

```
System.out.print("\n some text");
```

You can instead use

```
System.out.println("some text");
```

On to the next issue.

After you do your `System.out.print`s, you wrote

```
pick = br.readLine();
pick = array1[a];
```

What's the point of reading in the first place? You set pick to the user input, but then you set pick to `array1[a]`. I think you meant to say

```
array[a] = br.readLine();
```

Now for the long a short. This (very) revised version of your code should work:

```
package pack;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String[] array1 = new String[4];

        for (int a = 0; a < array1.length; a++) {
            System.out.print("\n Pick an exception: ");
            System.out.print("\n A. Arithmetic Exception");
            System.out.print("\n B. Array Out Of Bounds Exception");
            System.out.print("\n C. Array Store Exception");
            System.out.print("\n D. Number Format Exception");
            System.out.print("\n\nPick: ");
            try {
                array1[a] = in.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        boolean a = false;
        boolean b = false;
        boolean c = false;
        boolean d = false;

        for (String i : array1) {
            if (i.equals("a")) {
                if(a)
                    System.err.println("Repeat!");
                a = true;
            } else if (i.equals("b")) {
                if(b)
                    System.err.println("Repeat!");
                b = true;
            } else if (i.equals("c")) {
                if(c)
                    System.err.println("Repeat!");
                c = true;
            } else {
                if(d)
                    System.err.println("Repeat!");
                d = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's really inefficient, but it'll do.